# Cassandra Python driver error(Memory leak while creating sessions)

Tags: python-2.7, cassandra

I am changing the original post to memory leak, as what i have observed that cassandra python driver do not release sessions from memory. And during heavy inserts its eat up all the memory (Thus crashes cassandra as not enough room left for GC).

This was raised earlier but i see the issue in latest drivers as well.

https://github.com/datastax/python-driver/pull/131

```
     In [2]: cassandra.__version__
     Out[2]: '2.1.4'

class SimpleClient(object):
session = None

def connect(self, nodes):
    cluster = Cluster(nodes)
    metadata = cluster.metadata
    self.session = cluster.connect()
    logging.info('Connected to cluster: ' + metadata.cluster_name)
    for host in metadata.all_hosts():
        logging.info('Datacenter: %s; Host: %s; Rack: %s', host.datacenter, host.address, host.rack)
        print ("Datacenter: %s; Host: %s; Rack: %s"%(host.datacenter, host.address, host.rack))

def close(self):
    self.session.cluster.shutdown()
    logging.info('Connection closed.')

def main():
    logging.basicConfig()
    client = SimpleClient()
    client.connect(['127.0.0.1'])
    client.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
     count = 0
     while count != 1:
           main()
          time.sleep(1)
```

If any one have found the solution of it please share.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart, I think he is talking about Cassandra GC causing the connections to get timed out, hence the exceptions

Comment: I apologize for my ignorance of Cassandra - I thought the OP was referring to the Python GC.

Comment: Yes.. I apologies yes i am talking about Cassandra GC pause.. But i am not able to determine if the errors are causing by gc pause. cause Cassandra not logging anything.  I am using the datastax version of cassandra.

Answer (score 1):

I think GC is very likely. Depending on how much data you are inserting (and how fast) you could be causing a rather long pause on the C* side. The python driver keeps a constant connection to the C* database which it occasionally pings for cluster state information. The error you are seeing is this connection failing to actually receive data.

You should be able to see in your Cassandra logs a record of each GC and it's duration.

Comment: Thanks Russ, i believe this is whats happening. i am right now not sure how i am going to deal with this. Do i need to set timeout or put a pause while inserting data like time.sleep() or something else?

Comment: Without knowing more about your system it's hard for me to offer advice. If you are using batch statements the fastest way to fix this issues is to stop using batch statements. If you are doing a lot of inserts you can try increasing the portion of the JVM dedicated to new objects. Again without details it's hard to tell

Answer (score 1):

There was an issue where registering shutdown hooks was keeping Cluster references around. This is resolved in driver version 3.4.0.

[JIRA](https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/PYTHON-135)

[PR](https://github.com/datastax/python-driver/pull/565)